# Defining complex workflow dependency in airflow 2.0 taskflow API

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Let's say I have the follow dummy DAG defined as below:

```
@dag(default_args=default_args,
     schedule_interval=None,
     start_date=days_ago(2))
def airflow_taskflow_api_dag():
    cur_day = '2020-01-01'

    @task()
    def A(current_day: str):
        return current_day + ' 10'

    @task(multiple_outputs=True)
    def B(current_date_time: str):
        timestamp = calendar.timegm(
            datetime.strptime(
                current_date_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H').timetuple())

        another_current_date_time_format = '2020-01-01T10:00:00'

        return {
            "timestamp": timestamp,
            "new_cur_date_time": another_current_date_time_format
        }

    @task()
    def C(livy_batch_id, start_time: str):
        logging.info("Executing task C {}".format(start_time))
       return "c_id"

    @task()
    def D(upstream_id, start_time: str):
        logging.info("Executing task D {}".format(start_time))

    # workflow dependencies
    get_current_time = A(cur_day)
    new_date_time = B(get_current_time)

    livy_task = LivyOperator(
        task_id='livy_task',
        file="dummy_file",
        class_name="dummy_class",
        args=[
            new_date_time['timestamp']
        ],
        driver_memory='1G',
        driver_cores='4',
        executor_memory='1G',
        executor_cores='4',
        num_executors='4',
        queue='default_queue',
        livy_conn_id='livy_conn_id'
    )

    c_task = C(livy_task.output, new_date_time['new_cur_date_time'])

    d_task = D(c_task, new_date_time['new_cur_date_time'])

airflow_taskflow_api_dag = airflow_taskflow_api_dag()
```

If I wrote my DAG like this (passing two params from upstream tasks), the dependency would be like:
[image: Screen Shot 2021-03-11 at 3 17 37 PM]

But I want to define the dependency with: A >> B >> livy_task >> C >> D

Is there a way to do this by using taskflow api? It seems like if I pass the task B's output to livy_task, C and D, the three tasks will be run in parallel.

Thanks!

Comment: can you not return the "new_cur_date_time" as part of livy_task and then use the two varibles to kick of C, which then return the same "new_cur_date_time" to D?

Answer (score 0):

Your current dependency graph could be represented in `Airflow 1.10.*` syntax as:

```
A >> B >> [C, D, livy_task]
livy_task >> C >> D
```

> But I want to define the dependency with: A >> B >> livy_task >> C >> D

According to this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361899/18504339), **it's not possible to remove existing edges** in this dependency graph, while keeping the existing operators.

**Reason:**
In the case of `B >> D`, the dependency exists because the output of `B`, `new_date_time`, is one of the inputs for `D`.

There's no way (yet) to remove hide those implicit edges in UI, but they shouldn't impact your execution flow since trigger_rule by default is `all_success`.

Extra Note:
If you wanted to add more edges, that'd be simple, since Taskflow API supports setting dependencies using bitwise operators (ie. `livy_task >> D`)