# Airflow DAG Steps Dependencies

Tags: amazon-emr, airflow

I have Airflow DAG written as below:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='dag',
    default_args={
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
    },
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=2),
    start_date=datetime(2021, 9, 28, 11),
    schedule_interval='10 * * * *'
) as dag:

    create_job_flow = EmrCreateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='create_job_flow',
        job_flow_overrides=JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        emr_conn_id='emr_default',
    )

    job_step = EmrAddStepsOperator(
        task_id='job_step',
        job_flow_id=create_job_flow.output,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
        steps=JOB_SETP,
    )

    job_step_sensor = EmrStepSensor(
        task_id='job_step_sensor',
        job_flow_id=create_job_flow.output,
        step_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='job_step', key='return_value')[0] }}",
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )

    read_file = PythonOperator(
        task_id="read_file",
        python_callable=get_date_information
    )

    alter_partitions = PythonOperator(
        task_id="alter_partitions",
        python_callable=update_partitions
    )

    remove_cluster = EmrTerminateJobFlowOperator(
        task_id='remove_cluster',
        job_flow_id=create_job_flow.output,
        aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    )


    create_job_flow.set_downstream(job_step)
    job_step.set_downstream(job_step_sensor)
    job_step_sensor.set_downstream(read_file)
    read_file.set_downstream(alter_partitions)
    alter_partitions.set_downstream(remove_cluster)
```

So this is basically creating an EMR cluster, starting a Step in it and sensing that step. Then execute some Python functions and finally terminate the cluster. The view of the DAG in Airflow UI is as below:

[image]

Here, create_job_flow is also pointing to remove_cluster (maybe because the job_flow_id has a reference to create_job_flow) whereas I only set the downstream of alter_partitions to remove_cluster. Would this happen that before reaching job_step, it would remove the cluster as in that case the cluster will already be deleted before executing the split_job_step and hence that is the problem. Is there any way to remove the link between create_job_flow and remove_cluster? Or would it wait to finish alter_partitions and would then execute remove_cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "remove_cluster" task will wait until the "alter_partitions" task is completed.  The extra edge between "create_job_flow" and "remove_cluster" (as well as between "create_job_flow" and "job_step_sensor") is a feature of the TaskFlow API and the `XComArg` concept, namely the use of an operator's `.output` property. (Check out [this documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/taskflow.html#taskflow) for another example.)

In both the "remove_cluster" and "job_step_sensor" tasks, `job_flow_id=create_job_flow.output` is an input arg. Behind the scenes, when an operator's `.output` is used in a templated field as an input of another task, a dependency is automatically created. This feature ensures what were previously implicit task dependencies between tasks using other tasks' `XComs` are now explicit.

This pipeline will execute serially as written and desired (assuming the `trigger_rule` is "all_success" which is the default). The "remove_cluster" task won't execute until both the "create_job_flow" and "alter_partitions" tasks are complete (which is effectively a serial execution).